# Are any of the Silent Hill Games related ? No Spoilers please

Tags: silent-hill-series

I was a huge fan of Silent Hill 1 + 2 but simply never got round to playing any of the others ... I was wondering if any of the games after 1+2 had connected storylines or characters ? (seeing as there are 8? games now ive found it hard to keep track of everything thats going on in the world of Silent Hill)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

3 is a direct sequel to 1.  Beyond that, there are some less obvious connections and thematic bonds but none of them can be said to be beyond-a-doubt connected.  There is a very strong argument for 0rigin being in continuity with 1 and 3, a weaker one for 2 and 4, and beyond that who knows...this is a pretty loaded question because it's a major point of contention in the fanbase.  Like a lot of things in Silent Hill, nothing's ever spelled out clearly.

Comment: 3 seems to be the obvious choice then :) especially with the second movie seemingly being based around that as well

Comment: This probably makes me a heretic but 3 is my favorite (even more than 2!)

Comment: Oh, and Silent Hill Shattered Memories is a remake of the first game.

Comment: I'd call it more of a reimagining really. ;) (I just picked it up and haven't played it yet but I'm really excited!)

Comment: Update - I finished Shattered Memories and it's great.  I'd like to think that IT is actually the canonical version of the plotline and all these others are variants. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe Silent Hill 4 started out as a Silent Hill game.

Comment: care to expand on this anymore ?

Comment: Supposedly it was an independent project initially and then they decided to brand it Silent Hill for sales.  This explains some of the radical departures in the controls, inventory, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Silent Hill Origin was supposed to be a prequel, if that helps. When the town is just starting out. So you will see the girl Alessa, etc.